# How to display activity indicator in table view cell in ios7

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create an application having many images listed in a table view. Images are loading from the URLs stored in the array. I am using customized prototype cells having imageView, labels.If the image available in the Document directory then fetches it from there otherwise download from the url. Then Stores the image data on the document directory. At the time which it downloading, I want an ActivityIndicator at the middle of each cell in which image is downloading. I tried to connect activity indicator with the view, shows the error "illegal configuration". After that I have tried to connect with the tag value, but it is not showing.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
```

in cellForRowIndexPath function

and called as

```
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[activityIndicator atartAnimating];
```

But it is not showing, I also put Hide when stopping

Comment: Try to load image with AsyncImageView class check this demo code https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    [self setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];
}


- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder
{
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    NSArray *spinnerImagesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner1.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner2.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner3.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner4.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner5.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner6.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner7.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner8.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner9.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner10.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner11.png"]
                                   ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spinner12.png"], nil];
    // Remove in progress downloader from queue
    [manager cancelForDelegate:self];
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    self.animationImages = spinnerImagesArray;

    self.animationDuration = 0.7;
    self.animationRepeatCount = -1;
    [self startAnimating];
    //    self.image = placeholder;

    if (url)
    {
        [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self];
    }
    else
    {
        [self stopAnimating];
        self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image_available.png"];
    }
}
```

and call from your table view cell for row at index

```
 [cell.imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedRecipeImage.recipe_imageUrl]];
```

Comment: Thanks @Quality Coder, I have tried to use SDWebImageManager Package its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sudheesh, try to drag and drop the `UIActivityIndicatorView` directly to the interface builder in the prototype cell. Then you should make it a IBOutlet pressing CTRL and drag to the corresponding class.h. Pay attention to make a IBOutlet in the class you made for your cell, not in the class you have your `UITableView`. Also check out if you correctly set the Class for UITableCell in Identity Inspector (third tab in the left menu in XCode).

Comment: Thanks, I use StoryBoards and prototype cell is defined within the TableView itself, shows ana error _"Main.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: Connection "alertView" cannot have a prototype object as its destination"_.